# How to reload Excel custom functions?

Tags: excel, office-js, custom-functions-excel

I've deployed the [Excel-Custom-Functions](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Custom-Functions) sample successfully and can use the new JS functions.

After changing the code/definition in `customfunctions.js`, I've restarted my web server, started Excel, inserted the custom functions from the Office Add-ins page again but still get the original functions.

If I start Excel without inserting the sample again, the functions are still known!?

How can I force Excel to remove such an add-in and reload it from scratch?

Example:
The sample contains several custom functions and their corresponding registration:

```
Excel.Script.CustomFunctions["CONTOSO"]["ADD42"] = {
...
Excel.Script.CustomFunctions["CONTOSO"]["GETTEMPERATURE"] = {
...
```

Rename a function, and remove another function completely:

```
Excel.Script.CustomFunctions["CONTOSO"]["ADD42RENAMED"] = {
...
/* Excel.Script.CustomFunctions["CONTOSO"]["GETTEMPERATURE"] = {
...
```

Excel will still show the old metadata afterwards.

Comment: Please provide your the code you got so far and explain what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel caches previously-registered functions for each add-in. The reason for caching is so that the functions are available for the user to see and trigger (causing your add-in to load automatically) even before the add-in gets loaded.

When you run the following code, all previous registered functions in the cache are removed and immediately replaced with the new ones you specify:

```js
Excel.run(function (context) {        
    context.workbook.customFunctions.addAll();
    return context.sync().then(function(){});
}).catch(function(error){});
```

Edit: if you still see functions that you don't think are supposed to be registered after you call the code above, there are 2 likely possibilities:

1. The "incorrect" functions were actually registered by a different add-in (perhaps an earlier test you were doing).
2. The `Excel.run` call is failing (you can check the `error` parameter to see whether this is your problem)

It may be useful to manually clear your computer's registration-cache: delete the folder AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef\CustomFunctions

-Michael, PM for add-ins

Comment: The code snippet you've proposed is already part of the sample. Looks like this does not work reliable. Or was this behavior fixed in a specific Excel version? I am using version 1711 (build 8711.2037), 32bit.

Comment: I've added some additional info to my answer

Comment: @MichaelSaunders Is this still valid? I can't find this api using ExcelApi 1.1